# Como somar os valores em um loop?

Tags: array, c++, operadores

Quero somar e mostrar o valor total da consulta. No caso de 3 pacientes a soma seria 1350. Mas algo está dando errado.

```
case 2 :


printf ("Particular:\n");
printf("O valor da consulta e de R$ 450,00: \n");
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
     printf("Digite o nome do paciente:");
     scanf("%s",&nome[i]);
     valorp[i]= valorp[i]+450.00;
     valortotal[i]=valorp[i];
     qtdpaciente = qtdpaciente +i;
}

printf("A quantidade de pacientes particulas foi: %i \n", qtdpaciente);
printf("o valor total de hoje foi: %.2f\n",valortotal[i]);


break;
```

Comment: O que está dando errado? Onde você está definindo `i`, `valorp` e `valortotal`? Crie um [MVCE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que possamos reproduzir o problema.

Comment: eu quero que  neste printf("o valor total de hoje foi: %.2f\n",valortotal[i]); ele mostre o valor de total as consultas .... no caso  acima meu for vai ate 3 portanto o valor final seria 1350.... mas o resultado que mostra é 0 ...  ja na variavel qtdpacientes  ele mostra corretamente ou seja o resultado de 3  que seria os 3 pacientes

Comment: @Tiago Resolveu? Acha que é suficiente para aceitar a resposta? Já viu o [tour]

Answer (score 2):

O código tem vários erros além de bem desorganizado. Não está pegando o nome corretamente. O valor total é um só, então não tem porque ele ser um vetor. O valor de cada paciente é único e não deve ser somado. Alguma coisa eu melhorei como otimização, quanto não ficar incrementando a quantidade de pacientes afinal já tem um incremento no laço. Não sei se as variáveis foram inicializadas corretamente já que não tem todo o código.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char nome[3][30];
    float valorPaciente[3];
    printf ("Particular:\n");
    printf("O valor da consulta e de R$ 450,00: \n");
    float valorTotal = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("Digite o nome do paciente:");
        scanf("%30s", nome[i]);
        valorPaciente[i] = 450.00;
        valorTotal += valorPaciente[i];
    }
    int qtdPaciente = i - 1; //precisa disto mes mo?
    printf("A quantidade de pacientes particulas foi: %i \n", qtdPaciente);
    printf("o valor total de hoje foi: %.2f\n", valorTotal);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9RlExi). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yybztysu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/MultipleErros.c).

Answer (score -2):

indo direto ao ponto:
valortotal[i]=valortotal[i]+valorp[i];

case 2 :

printf ("Particular:\n");
printf("O valor da consulta e de R$ 450,00: \n");
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
     printf("Digite o nome do paciente:");
     scanf("%s",&nome[i]);
     valorp[i]= valorp[i]+450.00;
     valortotal[i]=valorp[i];
     qtdpaciente = qtdpaciente +i;
}

printf("A quantidade de pacientes particulas foi: %i \n", qtdpaciente);
printf("o valor total de hoje foi: %.2f\n",valortotal[i]);

break;